# How to click checkbox in Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click this checkbox and select an option from the dropdown menu. The dropdown object has a value of "Open" and the dropdown ID is "StatusCheck". Relevant HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" id="StatusCheck" name="StatusCheck"> ==$
```

And dropdown HTML

```
<select name="Status" class="input" style="font-size:10px;">
<option value="ALL">All Open and Closed Service Requests</option>
<option selected="" value="OPEN">All Open Service Requests</option>
<option value="CLOSED">All Closed Service Requests</option>
<option value="SCHEDULED">Only Scheduled Service Requests</option>
<option value="ASSIGNED">Only Assigned Service Requests</option>
<option value="DISPATCHED">Only Dispatched Service Requests</option>
<option value="IN_PROGRESS">Only In-Progress Service Requests</option>
<option value="BACKORDER">Only Backorder Service Requests</option>
<option value="SUSPENDED">Only Suspended Service Requests</option>
<option value="COMPLETED">Only Completed Service Requests</option>
<option value="CANCELLED">Only Cancelled Service Requests</option>
</select>
```

Then my script is as follows

```
#Check display box
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.find_element_by_ID("StatusCheck").click()
#Select All Open and Closed Service Requests from dropdown
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
dropdownSelector = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("Status"))
dropdownSelector.select_by_value("OPEN")
```

Error is as follows

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Temp\ATMStatusScript.py1\main.py", line 40, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id("StatusCheck").click()
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\tmartin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="StatusCheck"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)
```

EDIT: As JeffC pointed out, this is within an iFrame. The iFrame HTML is as follows:

```
<iframe id="myframe" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); width: 100%; position: absolute; height: 829px; display: block;" src="/f5-w-687474703a2f2f6e617973636c75737465722e6e63722e636f6d3a3830$$/MSL/jsp/MSLReDirect.jsp?ep=GIMV"></iframe>
```

There is also another frame in the code if this matters, which is this:

```
<frame src="f5-h-$$/GIM/GIM?TARGET_PROCESSOR=com.ncr.gim.processor.OPFProcessor&amp;REQ=GIMA&amp;pageAccess=&amp;LAZ=Tue Mar 30 08:46:58 EDT 2021" name="GIMA" frameborder="0" border="0" scrolling="auto">
```

I tried this and it still didn't work. Wondering if maybe I need to handle the frame differently than the iFrame or if I can maybe just ignore it?

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe"))
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("body > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > a").click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    #Check display box
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("myframe"))
    #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("GIMA"))
    driver.find_element_by_id("StatusCheck").click()
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
    #Select All Open and Closed Service Requests from dropdown
    el = WebDriverWait(driver, 15) \
        .until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='Status' and @class='input']")))
    dropdownSelector = Select(el)
    dropdownSelector.select_by_value("OPEN")
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if it's in an IFRAME? Have you tried the locator in the browser and make sure that it's unique? For CSS selector use `$$()` and for XPath `$x()`. So in your INPUT case, you would use `$$("#StatusCheck")`. How many elements does it return?

Comment: Also `implicitly_wait()` doesn't actually wait... it sets the wait timeout. Set it once and you don't need to set it again unless you want to change the timeout. Also, the Selenium devs have said that you shouldn't use `implicitly_wait()`, you should use `WebDriverWait()` instead.

Comment: Ahhh man... Thanks JeffC! There's 2 iFrames in the set and one was closed prior. Didn't realize it was in a separate iFrame. Good call, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are receiving is selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="StatusCheck"]"}

It does not appear to be related to the dropdown.
It looks like the checkbox does not exist (object is not initialized) when you do the findElement.
Try using a long sleep before your code and look manually in the developer tools. If I'm right, you will not be able to locate the object manually as well.

Comment: He located it... the HTML is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try that out, might help:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


el = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)\
    .until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//select[@name='Status' and @class='input']")))
dropdownSelector = Select(el)
dropdownSelector.select_by_value("OPEN")
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately with that, I'm still getting the following:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="StatusCheck"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.90)

Comment: @Tyler have you switched to iframe first?

Comment: @Tyler try to switch to frame like: driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id('myframe'))

Comment: Yes, in my edit I show the new version. I used 
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("myframe"))
    #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name("GIMA"))
    driver.find_element_by_id("StatusCheck").click()
which resulted in the same error unfortunately. Not sure if maybe I have to handle the regular frame as well? But I tried it in the same way I'd handle an iFrame and got the same error both ways which is why it is commented out here.